# how can i acces website on linux server?

Tags: server, apache2, openssh

I have installed `ntopng` in my  linux server and `ntopng` has web interface.

But linux server doesn't and i want to connect my linux server somehow to my other computer in the same network which has windows and i can use web browser to go

> http://yourserver.name:3000

and remotely use `ntopng`.

I have downloaded redis-server, Apache2, openssh, and i can remotely controll it via putty but when i open web browser in windows and put

> myserverip:3000

it wont connect.

Comment: Is it on purpose that you are using yourserver.name:3000 vs myserverip:3000?

Comment: Consider checking the logs of the server - in case of apache the error-log should be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: well .. when you say myserverip:3000 .. are you trying to use a local address or internet address .. like 192.168.0.20:3000 ... or 76.45.124.25:3000?

Comment: im using server ip address wich is 192.168.2.171

Answer (score 0):

My router also doesn't let me to connect to a local server with it's internet ip or domain name (other routers have no problem with that). You must use the local ip (use command `ifconfig` to find it out). For exapmle, in my case in order to connect to my apache website:

- From a pc in the same network I use `192.168.2.222` (my servers static local ip).
- From an external pc I use `lichking.ddns.net` (the domain name which I created with `noip` and it automatically directs to my servers ip (not the local ip but the internet ip which is something like `79.166.120.230` and it changes with every router restart).